Hair Curves attached to character's surface lose their UV map while using keyframed animation Using Surface Rest Position fixes UV but breaks position
I have hair Curves attached to a character's surface. The character is rigged. Posing the character looks great, but the moment i animate the character over time the curves material/UV is busted. I am able to resolve the material/UV issue by using "Surface Rest Position" during interpolate/attach. But using surface rest position breaks the positioning of the curves so it no longer aligns with the mesh.
Is there a reason "Surface rest position" is giving me strange results? My characters rest position is in its T-pose state. I imagine that this is the main issue I need to resolve.
Or perhaps there is a better method for applying the UVs of my curves? Can I bake the curve UVs after creation?
The images attached have descriptions to help.
Any help would be appreciated! I am a Maya user, and new to blender. Thank you







I redid the hair/fur without converting it to geometry and everything works as needed. The deformation tools are nice for particle->hair converted to geometry but there are definitely some quirks. I would recommend others keep their hair as a particle system if they ever want it to animate. It renders faster and gives you better control in many ways.
